# Unable to loop through values using for - Laravel 5.6 Blade Template

Tags: php, laravel

The value of the for loop is stuck at 1.

I am trying to run this loop to print the name of the event at the top of the modal box. But the same name appears each time.

I've given continue statement and tried too. Yet the value of $i is stuck at 1

It would be of great help if you could find a solution for this

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php  $noofevents = DB::table('events')->count(); ?>

@for($i = 1; $i <= $noofevents; $i++)

<?php $current_event_name = DB::table('events')->where('id',$i)->value('Event_Name'); ?>

<div id="sponsor-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">                        
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header text-center">                          
                <h4 class="display-4" style = "text-align : center; font-size : 30px;">Sponsors for {{$current_event_name}}</h4>                        
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">                         
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <img src ="{{asset('images/Sponsors/paytm.jpg')}}" alt ="" width = "200px" class = "mx-auto d-block">
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <p class = "text-center"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">                         
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                      
             </div>                     
         </div>
     </div>                      
</div>
@endfor
```

Comment: Because you have __several__ modal windows with same id `sponsor-modal`. `id` must be __unique__ on the page.

Comment: can you echo `$noofevents`

Comment: Have you tried using `@php` instead of `<? php`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#php Also avoid using PHP in your templates, add the events in your controller and assign them to your view, then loop over them

Comment: @u_mulder I removed the id attribute and changed sponsor-modal to a class. Still its not working

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya It gives me the correct count of records in the events table

Comment: There is logic in this view that should be in a Controller class though.

Comment: why not retrieve all events at first and loop through them than getting the count of all events and then retrieve event from database per iteration?

Comment: So, obviously that's not enough. You should also modify code that opens the modal so as it opens __the correct window__. Open your html-source and see that you have all modal windows there with correct data.

Comment: @u_mulder I did that too already.

Comment: @Wreigh 
@foreach($events = Event::orderBy('id')->get() as $event).
Do you mean like this?

Comment: i think you should append the event ID to the id of the modal. related with what @u_mulder said

Comment: Thought about that  too. Will do it and clarify @Wreigh

Comment: <button type = "button" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = '{{#sponsor-modal{$event->id} }}'> . Is this right? @Wreigh

Comment: yes. enclose it with double quotes since it's a string: "#sponsor-modal{$event->id}", also apply that to the modal's id.

Comment: @Wreigh I did that  and the names of the events appear correctly, but then the modal doesn't open

Comment: Thanks a lot guys @Wreigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate modal box with different ids

Please Use this part in your controller and pass it to your blade view using compact.

```
<?php  $noofevents = DB::table('events')->count(); ?>
```

Use this part in blade :

```
@for($i = 1; $i <= $noofevents; $i++)

<?php $current_event_name = DB::table('events')->where('id',$i)->value('Event_Name'); ?>


<div id="sponsor-modal{{ $i }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

 <div class="modal-dialog">

     <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header text-center">

            <h4 class="display-4" style = "text-align : center; font-size : 30px;">Sponsors for {{$current_event_name}}</h4>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="row">





               <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="card">

                        <div class="card-content">

                            <img src ="{{asset('images/Sponsors/paytm.jpg')}}" alt ="" width = "200px" class = "mx-auto d-block">

                        </div>

                        <div class="card-footer">





                            <p class = "text-center"></p>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>




        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

         </div>


     </div>

 </div>

</div>



@endfor
```

So now you have different modal boxes for total noofevents. you need to call this modal boxes with ids appended by $i.